# Background image disappearing on resize

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, custom-post-type

This might be a simple one but I can't workout out - Can Anyone tell me why my background image disappears below 860px wide here?

http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/qualifications/

I have checked all of the responsive media queries I'm using but I cans spot one that would take the background image away.

Here's the code used to pull those boxes through:

```
<!-- Main Content =========================================== -->

<div class="wrap">
      <?php
        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'qualifications',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      ?>

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <a class="one-half qualifications-block" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('qualification_thumb'); ?>); background-size: 150%">

              <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>

        </a>

      <?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
      <?php if ( $products_count % 2 == 0): ?>

        <!-- Enter something here to appear after 2 items - New row div would be: </div><div class="row"> -->

      <?php endif; ?>


      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
</div>
```

I can't for the life of be find out why the background image would disappear when it goes below 860px and the boxes change to 100% in width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images set with background-image on a tags will disappear if they are not set to display: block. So maybe somewhere in your media queries this tag is not set correct

Appears

```
<a class="one-half qualifications-block" style="background-image: 
url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'); display: block"
</a>
```

Disappears

```
<a class="one-half qualifications-block" style="background-image: 
url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');"
</a>
```

Comment: Ah thank you - I guess the first thing to check is the element itself after something changes! Thanks a lot, Ive made sure the display:block; is there oval sizes.

Comment: Yea thats a wierd one. i would have made the same error.

Answer (score 1):

it is because some css of these blocks reside with in @media (min-width:860px){} so you need to put this within css and adjust it according to  yours

```
 @media (max-width:859px){
a.one-half {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 1%;
}
}
```